# mysqli_affected_rows() returns -1 but query works

Tags: php, mysql, netbeans, mysqli, xdebug

All my mysql functions seem to be having this problem. The simple insert statement works, but when I check the affected rows, it returns `-1`.

This works, a new row is inserted into the database with it, but debugger shows the mysqli_affected_rows as `-1`, and therefore the else block gets run:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES ('$email', '$password')";

mysqli_query($this->connection, $query) or die('Query failed in register.');


if (mysqli_affected_rows($this->connection)>0)  {
    //this doesnt get run, 
}
else {
   // this is run
}
```

Why would this happen?

**Edit:**

- I'm using Netbeans, Xdebug, WAMP.
- When I view the connection immediately after it is created, the affected rows is already set to -1.
- After running a successful query, the connection still shows -1, before doing the affected rows check.
- No error messages or error numbers are seen in the connection object.

Comment: What about `if (mysqli_affected_rows($this->connection, $query)>0)`

Comment: Didn't work, still -1

Comment: Can you paste your query, `mysqli_affected_rows` returns `-1` on query error

Comment: Why do you think it returns `-1`?

Comment: No idea why it returns -1. Almost like the query uses one connection and the mysqli_affected_rows uses another. Seems to be a problem with the connection some how.

Comment: @Andrew: you didn't get it. Why do you think it's -1 there? Did you check it somehow? Why do you think it's not 0?

Comment: I can see that the content doesn't get run in the if statement. And the debugger says it is -1.

Comment: `if` statement won't run even if it's `0`. What if you output it explicitly with `var_dump()`?

Comment: The `mysql_` functions have been deprecated for a while, and there is a reason for that. You may want to try *mysqli*.

Comment: What do you have between the *query* and *affected_rows*? Any other mysql calls?

Comment: `-1` means an error, and `mysqli_error()` must provide it.

Comment: i think there is an error with your debugger

http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/23848434/netbeans-xdebug-mysqli-affected-rows-returns-1-when-it-should-be-1/23848759#23848759

Comment: Try This $ar=mysqli_affected_rows($this->connection); if($ar>0){ }

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem. I've investigated the issue with Netbeans and Xdebug and it seems this is a bug in the MySQLi extension itself. An according [bug report](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67348)  has been made. In the meantime you can instead use a more forgiving Expression, e.g.

```
if (mysqli_sqlstate($dbc) == 00000) {
//your code
}
```

to continue debugging your remaining code.

Comment: Decent idea checking for an error at least if not the affected rows... However, that bug report indicates $dbc->stat causes the affected_rows to become -1, but I am not using the stat feature.

Comment: Thank you! The bug still exists at this time on Linux Mint 19 with MariaDB Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.38-MariaDB and php 7.2.17.